# IOS 7 game center

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to use Game Center to achieve peer to peer communication. But I meet some issues while testing game center. The user authentication is fine, it went through. The problem is matchmaking.

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
 if (error) {
     NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
 }else if (match != nil) {
     NSLog(@"good match");
     [match setDelegate:self];
 }else {
     NSLog(@"other error");
 }

 }];
```

I want to create own request instead of using GKMatchmakerViewController. But the block code is NOT steady, some time it can work, some time gives me error: cannot connect to server, I don't know it's Game Center server's problem or my code?

Once the above code is working fine, then I set the following handler:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.playersToInvite=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"G:****", nil];//yin
request.inviteMessage=@"Welcome to my Game";
request.inviteeResponseHandler=^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse response) {
    if(response==0){
        NSLog(@"Accepted....");
    }else if(response==1){
         NSLog(@"Declined....");
    }else if(response==2){
         NSLog(@"Failed....");
    }else if(response==3){
         NSLog(@"3");
    }else if(response==4){
        NSLog(@"4");
    }else if(response==5){
        NSLog(@"5");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"unknown...");
    }
};
```

I tested on different iphone. Once one iphone sends request to other, other can receive the notification, but only other rejects the invitation, then sender iphone can receive, if other accepts, the sender iphone receive nothing. I don't know why this things happened????
And at the receiver iphone side the inviteHandler is working fine. This is wired I tested the whole day, I cannot make it through. I am very brand new with IOS developing. Please help me out of this, appreciate very much!!!!